# What is the proper way to show blank menu item for SelectField (material-ui, react)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, jsx

I use [select-field](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/select-field) from material-ui framework of latest 0.15.4 version with react of version 15.4.0. I try to add blank menu-item to select-field to be able to diselect value for 'dropdown' field when I click on it. When I try to add it in the way like

```
<MenuItem value="" primaryText="" />
```

it doesn't appear in the dropdown list of items. What is the proper way to add functionality of selection blank field in SelectField?

Comment: Maybe you should use a [Divider](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/divider)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

setting the MenuItem value to "" and primaryText to "" will make it invisible in the choices.

I suggest you do this:

```
<SelectField value={this.state.some_key}>
    <MenuItem value="Choice1" primaryText="Choice1" />
    <MenuItem value="Select" primaryText="Select" />
</SelectField>
```

and then on onChange:

```
onChange = (event, index, value) => {
    if(value === "Select") {
        this.setState({some_key = ""})
    }
}
```

This will show blank input on the field once the "Select" is clicked.

Comment: ok, thanks. It definitely will work and I already use this way, but it looks tricky, if I don't want to show empty MenuItem without "Choice1".